# Mod rewrite rewrites url from lower case to upper case on localhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So if I have a **directrory named CONTENT** and the url like localhost/**content**/something .
MR rewrites the url to www.localhost/**CONTENT**/something. 
I don´t use nc flag in the rules and !-f and !-d cond. have not effect to this(it´s the same if they are in coments or not). 
My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#ignore all real files (php skripts, imgs, styles)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#ignore all real directories
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/myCMS/$1 [R=301,L]  # localhost
######RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]  # real hosting

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
#####RewriteRule ^(.*)$ indexTest.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there some seting in httpd.conf for case sens default? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out the reason is that the Windows don´t make case sensitive comparison of the dir names. So if he should find "contend" and there is reall directory named "CONTEND" he use UC dir name for everything else.